# Espacio entre filas tabla HTML

Tags: html, css, html-tabla

No se donde puede estar el error, pero tengo una tabla HTML en la que quiero que no tenga espacio entre filas y esten todas juntas.

Si yo pongo esta table en JSFiddle funciona pero cuando la utizo en mi sitio Web y falla.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="articulo" id="articulo" onchange="change_documento90();  change_documento91()" onKeyUp="formula()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>

          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>

          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
 
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
 
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
   
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario" value="" onKeyUp="formula()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento" value="" onKeyUp="formula()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva" id="iva" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total" value="" onKeyUp="formula()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion" value="" onKeyUp="formula()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario" value="" onKeyUp="formula()" />
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad1" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula1()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo1" name="articulo1" onchange="change_documento92();  change_documento93()" onKeyUp="formula1()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario1" value="" onKeyUp="formula1()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento1" value="" onKeyUp="formula1()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva1" id="iva1" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total1" value="" onKeyUp="formula1()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion1" value="" onKeyUp="formula1()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario1" value="" onKeyUp="formula1()" />
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad2" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula2()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo2" name="articulo2" onchange="change_documento94();  change_documento95()" onKeyUp="formula2()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario2" value="" onKeyUp="formula2()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento2" value="" onKeyUp="formula2()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva2" id="iva2" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total2" value="" onKeyUp="formula2()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion2" value="" onKeyUp="formula2()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario2" value="" onKeyUp="formula2()" />
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad3" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula3()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo3" name="articulo3" onchange="change_documento96();  change_documento97()" onKeyUp="formula3()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario3" value="" onKeyUp="formula3()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento3" value="" onKeyUp="formula3()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva3" id="iva3" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total3" value="" onKeyUp="formula3()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion3" value="" onKeyUp="formula3()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario3" value="" onKeyUp="formula3()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad4" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula4()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo4" name="articulo4" onchange="change_documento98();  change_documento99()" onKeyUp="formula4()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario4" value="" onKeyUp="formula4()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento4" value="" onKeyUp="formula4()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva4" id="iva4" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total4" value="" onKeyUp="formula4()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion4" value="" onKeyUp="formula4()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario4" value="" onKeyUp="formula4()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad5" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula5()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo5" name="articulo5" onchange="change_documento100();  change_documento101()" onKeyUp="formula5()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario5" value="" onKeyUp="formula5()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento5" value="" onKeyUp="formula5()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva5" id="iva5" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total5" value="" onKeyUp="formula5()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion5" value="" onKeyUp="formula5()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario5" value="" onKeyUp="formula5()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad6" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula6()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo6" name="articulo6" onchange="change_documento102();  change_documento103()" onKeyUp="formula6()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario6" value="" onKeyUp="formula6()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento6" value="" onKeyUp="formula6()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva6" id="iva6" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total6" value="" onKeyUp="formula6()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion6" value="" onKeyUp="formula6()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario6" value="" onKeyUp="formula6()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad7" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula7()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo7" name="articulo7" onchange="change_documento104();  change_documento105()" onKeyUp="formula7()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario7" value="" onKeyUp="formula7()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento7" value="" onKeyUp="formula7()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva7" id="iva7" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total7" value="" onKeyUp="formula7()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion7" value="" onKeyUp="formula7()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario7" value="" onKeyUp="formula7()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad8" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula8()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo8" name="articulo8" onchange="change_documento106();  change_documento107()" onKeyUp="formula8()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario8" value="" onKeyUp="formula8()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento8" value="" onKeyUp="formula8()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva8" id="iva8" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total8" value="" onKeyUp="formula8()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion8" value="" onKeyUp="formula8()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario8" value="" onKeyUp="formula8()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad9" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula9()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo9" name="articulo9" onchange="change_documento108();  change_documento109()" onKeyUp="formula9()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario9" value="" onKeyUp="formula9()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento9" value="" onKeyUp="formula9()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva9" id="iva9" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total9" value="" onKeyUp="formula9()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion9" value="" onKeyUp="formula9()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario9" value="" onKeyUp="formula9()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad10" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula10()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo10" name="articulo10" onchange="change_documento110();  change_documento111()" onKeyUp="formula10()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario10" value="" onKeyUp="formula10()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento10" value="" onKeyUp="formula10()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva10" id="iva10" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total10" value="" onKeyUp="formula10()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion10" value="" onKeyUp="formula10()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario10" value="" onKeyUp="formula10()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad11" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula11()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo11" name="articulo11" onchange="change_documento112();  change_documento113()" onKeyUp="formula11()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario11" value="" onKeyUp="formula11()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento11" value="" onKeyUp="formula11()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva11" id="iva11" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total11" value="" onKeyUp="formula11()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion11" value="" onKeyUp="formula11()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario11" value="" onKeyUp="formula11()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad12" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula12()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo12" name="articulo12" onchange="change_documento114();  change_documento115()" onKeyUp="formula12()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario12" value="" onKeyUp="formula12()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento12" value="" onKeyUp="formula12()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva12" id="iva12" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total12" value="" onKeyUp="formula12()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion12" value="" onKeyUp="formula12()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario12" value="" onKeyUp="formula12()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad13" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula13()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo13" name="articulo13" onchange="change_documento116();  change_documento117()" onKeyUp="formula13()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario13" value="" onKeyUp="formula13()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento13" value="" onKeyUp="formula13()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva13" id="iva13" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total13" value="" onKeyUp="formula13()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion13" value="" onKeyUp="formula13()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario13" value="" onKeyUp="formula13()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad14" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula14()">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="articulo14" name="articulo14" onchange="change_documento118();  change_documento119()" onKeyUp="formula14()" required>
          <option value=""> </option>
          echo
          <option value="cojin">cojin </option>
          echo
          <option value="mesa">mesa </option>
          echo
          <option value="Prueba">Prueba </option>
          echo
          <option value="silla">silla </option>
          echo
          <option value="sillon">sillon </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_unitario14" value="" onKeyUp="formula14()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento14" value="" onKeyUp="formula14()" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="iva14" id="iva14" disabled>
          <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total14" value="" onKeyUp="formula14()" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="recepcion14" value="" onKeyUp="formula14()" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" name="comentario14" value="" onKeyUp="formula14()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Si  tu web está en HTML5 no deberías poner los atributos `cellpadding` y `cellspacing` ya que no son válidos. Tampoco tiene sentido poner `border-spacing: 0` si tienes `border-collapse: collapse`, la propiedad `border-spacing` solo funciona cuando `border-collapse` tiene el valor `separate`

Comment: Entocnes si en `HTML 5` no funcionan cuales se usan ahora?

Comment: Se usa CSS solamente, `border-spacing` para la separación entre celdas y `padding` para el espacio interior de las celdas.

Comment: Se utiliza en `table`?

Comment: `border-spacing` en `table`, siempre que sea `border-collapse: separate` sino no hay espacio entre celdas que se pueda separar y `padding` en los `td`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probablemente en tu web se están sobrescribiendo las propiedades `css` de la tabla, ¿has examinado el `css` en el navegador para verlo?

Puedes probar con `important` para hacer que el `css` no sea sobrescrito:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
 }
```

Comment: No sabía lo de `!important` pero aún así tampoco funciona

Comment: Sin ver el código completo es difícil saber dónde está el problema, prueba revisando el css que afecta a la tabla en el navegador con botón derecho->inspeccionar elemento, problablemente necesites modificar más propiedades css, como puede ser el borde para tr y td.

Comment: Es por los `Select` que son mas grandes que los input

Answer (score 0):

Prueba acotando aun mas

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

td.celda_sin {

  padding: 0;

}
```

Y le aplicas a un par de celdas la class para ver si funciona